# send json object from jquery to angularjs and use ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, socket.io

I have a json object that come from node server as a variable "msg" and receive it by socket.on 
and I want to use this json with angularjs as ng-repeat 
please help !

```html
<script>
   var socket = io();

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $("ul").html(msg);


    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('jsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.msgs = msg;
});

    });


  </script>

<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in msgs">
         {{item.Name}}
      </li>
  </ul>
```

i have in server this code var

```html
initData = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>');
```

and I think I must use json.stringify(msg); to convert it to json

how can I use it with angular js ng-repeat !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
(function() {
        angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller("jsCtrl", jsCtrl);

        jsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

        function jsCtrl($scope) {
            var socket = io();

            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
                    $scope.msgs = angular.fromJson(msg);
                }
            }
        });
})();
```

It's just an idea, I don't know exactly what kind of data is coming.

Comment: thanks for replay , i have in server this code var initData = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>'); that send to me a json data like any json array